# How to purge an Gtk Table from all it's widgets

Tags: c, gtk

I am a newbie to gtk and c.

Using c and libglade for my program.

I am writing a program that needs to update a gtk table over and over depending on the combobox selection that was made by the user.

With initialization the gui has a vbox with an empty table in it. The user select an option from the combobox and depending on the selection the table is packed with widgets (labels and entryboxes). Should the user change his selection to a different option I need to clear the table of the previous widgets and pack the table with new appropriate widget for the selection.

I have tried to destroy the table widget and re-create a new table to add to the vbox but then I receive a Segmentation fault.

Is there a way of destroying the widgets in the table but not the table or a different way of doing what I want to do?

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you need to use a `GtkTreeView` with a `GtkListStore` instead of a table, and `GtkCellRendererText` instead of labels and entry boxes. The table isn't designed for displaying dynamic data.

Comment: Shows you how little I know about GTK!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `tblFoo.resize(0, 0)`?

Answer (score 0):

You can delete the existing table and create + add a new table where the old one was attached, e.g. inside a vertical box.